# How do I make the numbers on the y-axis show values in millions instead of in scientific notation in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

How do I change the numbers on the y-axis to show 0 to 17 million instead of 0 to 1.75 1e7?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pingouin as pg
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
```

```
data = pd.read_csv('COVID19_state.csv')
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
ax = sns.barplot(x = 'State', y = 'Tested', data = data, color='blue');
ax.set_title('Tested by State')
ax.set_xticklabels(labels=data['State'], rotation=90)
ax.set_ylabel('Tested')
ax.set_xlabel('State')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Output: [image: This plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found two options, the first gets the default `matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter` and turns off the scientific notation:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 2e7])
```

[image: default formatter without scientific notation]

The second method defines a custom formatter which divides by 1e6 and appends "million":

```
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter

def formatter(x, pos):
    return str(round(x / 1e6, 1)) + " million"

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 2e7])
```

[image: custom formatter]

I couldn't find a method in the `ScalarFormatter` that replaced 1e6 with "million", but I'm sure there is a method in matplotlib that lets you do that if you really want.

---

Edit: using `ax.text`:

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter

def formatter(x, pos):
    return str(round(x / 1e6, 1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 2e7])
ax.text(0, 1.05, "in millions", transform = ax.transAxes, ha = "left", va = "top")
```

[image: ax.text]

And of course if you already have a label it might make more sense to include it there, that's what I would do at least:

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter

def formatter(x, pos):
    return str(round(x / 1e6, 1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 2e7])
ax.set_ylabel("interesting_unit in millions")
```

[image: label]

If you make sure your data is already in millions and between `1e-4` and `1e5` (outside this range the [scientific notation will kick in](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html)), you can omit the whole part of setting the formatter in the last two methods and just add `ax.text(0, 1.05, "in millions", transform = ax.transAxes, ha = "left", va = "top")` or `ax.set_ylabel("interesting_unit in millions")` to your code. You will still need to set the formatters for the other two methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one string:

```py
plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(lambda x, loc: "{:.1f} млн".format(x / 1000000)))
```